# Mock attributes in Python mock?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, python-mock

I'm having a fairly difficult time using `mock` in Python:

```
def method_under_test():
    r = requests.post("http://localhost/post")

    print r.ok # prints "<MagicMock name='post().ok' id='11111111'>"

    if r.ok:
       return StartResult()
    else:
       raise Exception()

class MethodUnderTestTest(TestCase):

    def test_method_under_test(self):
        with patch('requests.post') as patched_post:
            patched_post.return_value.ok = True

            result = method_under_test()

            self.assertEqual(type(result), StartResult,
                "Failed to return a StartResult.")
```

The test actually returns the right value, but `r.ok` is a Mock object, not `True`. How do you mock attributes in Python's `mock` library?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You need to use [`return_value`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html?highlight=return_value#unittest.mock.Mock.return_value) and [`PropertyMock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.PropertyMock):

```
with patch('requests.post') as patched_post:
    type(patched_post.return_value).ok = PropertyMock(return_value=True)
```

This means: when calling `requests.post`, on the return value of that call, set a `PropertyMock` for the property `ok` to return the value `True`.

Comment: If I `print` the value of `r.ok` from in the `method_under_test`, I see `<MagicMock name='post().ok' id='57360464'>`, not `True`.

Comment: @TKKocheran: I have updated my answer. You also need to use a `PropertyMock`.

Comment: Why not simpy using `patched_post.return_value = mock.Mock(ok=True)`?

Comment: @lumbric Because you can use `PropertyMock` to assert that it was accessed like any other `Mock` object. By just assigning a value to the property you can't do that.

Answer (score 24):

A compact and simple way to do it is to use `new_callable` `patch`'s attribute to force `patch` to use `PropertyMock` instead of `MagicMock` to create the mock object. The  other arguments passed to `patch` will be used to create `PropertyMock` object.

```
with patch('requests.post.ok', new_callable=PropertyMock, return_value=True) as mock_post:
    """Your test"""
```

Answer (score 23):

With mock version '1.0.1' the simpler syntax mentioned in the question is supported and works as is!

Example code updated (py.test is used instead of unittest):

```
import mock
import requests


def method_under_test():
    r = requests.post("http://localhost/post")

    print r.ok

    if r.ok:
        return r.ok
    else:
        raise Exception()


def test_method_under_test():
    with mock.patch('requests.post') as patched_post:
        patched_post.return_value.ok = True

        result = method_under_test()
        assert result is True, "mock ok failed"
```

Run this code with: (make sure you install pytest)

```
$ py.test -s -v mock_attributes.py 
======= test session starts =======================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.10 -- py-1.4.30 -- pytest-2.7.2 -- /home/developer/miniconda/bin/python
rootdir: /home/developer/projects/learn/scripts/misc, inifile: 
plugins: httpbin, cov
collected 1 items 

mock_attributes.py::test_method_under_test True
PASSED

======= 1 passed in 0.03 seconds =================
```

Comment: FYI `requests.post.ok` is a property and not an attribute. If you try on simple object where `ok` is a simple attribute the *syntax mentioned in the question works* but for `requests.post.ok` object no: it will raise an `AttributeError`.

Comment: @Micheled'Amico thanks for your feedback, I tried please take a look ;-)