# mocking session in requests library

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

In my python code I have global `requests.session` instance:

```
import requests
session = requests.session()
```

How can I mock it with `Mock`? Is there any decorator for this kind of operations? I tried following:

```
session.get = mock.Mock(side_effect=self.side_effects)
```

but (as expected) this code doesn't return `session.get` to original state after each test, like `@mock.patch` decorator do.

Answer (score 17):

Since requests.session() returns an instance of the Session class, it is also possible to use patch.object()

```
from requests import Session
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch.object(Session, 'get')
def test_foo(mock_get):
    mock_get.return_value = 'bar'
```

Comment: Worked a treat for me.  Allowed me to use with http = requests.Session()

Comment: It saved me! Perfect.

Answer (score 6):

Use `mock.patch` to patch session in your module. Here you go, a complete working example https://gist.github.com/k-bx/5861641

Comment: add indents. This code is not readable and it doesn't patch session.

Comment: @amezhenin evaluate code from gist. This code works and it patches session.

Comment: could you make session global?

Answer (score 1):

With some inspiration from the previous answer and :

[mock-attributes-in-python-mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867509/mock-attributes-in-python-mock)

I was able to mock a session defined like this:

```
class MyClient(object):
    """
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.session()
```

with that: (the call to *get* returns a response with a *status_code* attribute set to 200)

```
def test_login_session():
    with mock.patch('path.to.requests.session') as patched_session:
        # instantiate service: Arrange
        test_client = MyClient()
        type(patched_session().get.return_value).status_code = mock.PropertyMock(return_value=200)

        # Act (+assert)
        resp = test_client.login_cookie()

        # Assert
        assert resp is None
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered [the requests_mock library](https://pypi.org/project/requests-mock/).  It saved me a lot of bother.  With pytest...

```
def test_success(self, requests_mock):
    """They give us a token.
    """
    requests_mock.get("https://example.com/api/v1/login", 
        text=(
          '{"result":1001, "errMsg":null,'
          f'"token":"TEST_TOKEN",' '"expire":1799}'))

    auth_token = the_module_I_am_testing.BearerAuth('test_apikey')

    assert auth_token == 'TEST_TOKEN'
```

The module I am testing has my `BearerAuth` class which hits an endpoint for a token to start a requests.session with.