# Mock a nested object in Python using Mock()

Tags: python, mocking

I have a parent object, which receives a connection object.

I run a method on this connection object to generate a config object. When I mock this, instead of `Foo` I get:

`<Mock name='mock().get_properties().property_c' id='1910891784064'>`

Code:

```
# Real

class ClassC:
    property_c = "Foo"

class ClassB:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def login(self):
        print("Logged in...")

    def get_properties(self):
        return ClassC()

class ClassA:
    def __init__(self, conn):
        self.conn = conn
        self.conn.login()

a = ClassA(conn=ClassB()) >>> Logged in...
result = a.conn.get_properties()
print(result.property_c) >>> Foo


# Mocked

from unittest.mock import Mock
mock_b = Mock()
mock_c = Mock()
mock_c.property_c.return_value = "Foo_Mock"
mock_b.get_properties.return_value = mock_c

a = ClassA(conn=mock_b())
result = a.conn.get_properties()
print(result.property_c) >>> Output shown above
```

How do I mock this properly?

### Edit1 - The suggested duplicate S.O answer only partially answers the question.

### Edit2 - I forgot to include the mock login behaviour

`mock_b.login.return_value = print("Logged in...")` awesoon's answer still works with this modification:

```
    mock_b = Mock()
    mock_c = Mock()
    type(mock_c).property_c = PropertyMock(return_value="Foo_Mock")
    mock_b.get_properties.return_value = mock_c
    mock_b.login.return_value = print("Logged in...")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mock attributes in Python mock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867509/mock-attributes-in-python-mock)

Comment: I see how PropertyMock can be used for ClassC, but how do I inject it into ClassB?

Comment: `type(mock_c).property_c = PropertyMock(return_value="Foo_Mock")` and `mock_b.get_properties().property_c` shall do the trick. Note I did not call `mock_b()`

Comment: I still get `<Mock name='mock().get_properties().property_c' id='1910891784064'>`

Comment: Check this one: https://ideone.com/aCy9Ye

Comment: `The suggested duplicate only partially answers the question` - I also explicitly listed all changes I made in the comment above. Read the note: `I did not call mock_b()` and you should not call it too because calling creates another mock which does not have `get_properties`.

Comment: I was referring to the flag at the top of this post by someone claiming that my question is a duplicate. If you paste your solution (that I upvoted) into an answer, then I can accept it and you'll  get credit

Comment: It was actually me, I still think this is a duplicate, because you were trying to use `return_value` to mock attribute. Also `mock_b.login.return_value = print("Logged in...")` is the same as printing `Logged in...` just before `mock_b.login.return_value = None`. `print("Logged in...")` will be executed immediately and it returns `None`. You may want to use `side_effect` with lambda instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

1. Do not call `mock_b` when passing to `ClassA` (`a = ClassA(conn=mock_b()`). Calling a mock will create another mock and it will not contain changes made to `mock_b`.
2. Use `PropertyMock` to mimic attribute:

   ```
   type(mock_c).property_c = PropertyMock(return_value="Foo_Mock")
   ```

   You can also set attribute explicitly, but `PropertyMock` is more flexible.

The final code is:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock, PropertyMock
mock_b = Mock()
mock_c = Mock()
type(mock_c).property_c = PropertyMock(return_value="Foo_Mock")
mock_b.get_properties.return_value = mock_c

print(mock_b.get_properties().property_c)
```

Outputs:

```
Foo_Mock
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is with this line:

```
a = ClassA(conn=mock_b())
```

You are creating here new mock. If you try below code:

```
mock_b = Mock(name='mock_b')
a = ClassA(conn=mock_b())
print(mock_b)
print(a.conn)
```

You will see that those, are two different mocks, with different IDs (for example):

```
<Mock name='mock_b' id='48709360'>
<Mock name='mock_b()' id='48709528'>
```

So frits of all, you need to replace `conn=mock_b()` by `conn=mock_b`.

If you fix that then you could call:

```
print(result.property_c())  # notice extra parathesis.
```

It would look better if you add `get_property` method to ClassC, and then mock method get_property.

Comment: I cannot structure it your way. I'm bound by the api

Comment: Ok, so you can simply change your 2 lines in your test:
`mock_c.property_c.return_value = "Foo_Mock"`  >> 
`mock_c.property_c = "Foo_Mock"`
and: 
`a = ClassA(conn=mock_b())`  >>  `a = ClassA(conn=mock_b)`