# pytest - Mocking constructor within constructor

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, pytest-mock

All,

I have a class similar to this.

```
from mod import Bar

class Foo:
  def __init__(self):
    self.obj = Bar()
```

How do I mock the `Bar` constructor using pytest / pytest-mock? I have tried the following unsuccessfully.

```
def test():
  with mock.patch('mod.Bar') as patched:
    Foo()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mock attributes in Python mock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867509/mock-attributes-in-python-mock)

Comment: @ConstantinGuidon I've included details from that post now. It is not working for me.

Comment: You have to patch "yourmodule.Bar" instead of "mod.Bar". See https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch for details.

Comment: @AlexanderFasching If you post an answer, I'll edit it an mark it as correct.

Comment: @AlexanderFasching How would one integrate this into an `@pytest.fixture`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to patch the name, not the instance.

From the official Python documentation: [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch)

> patch() works by (temporarily) changing the object that a name points to with another one. There can be many names pointing to any individual object, so for patching to work you must ensure that you patch the name used by the system under test.

In your example, your class `Foo` is defined in a module `foomod.py`, so you have to patch `foomod.Bar` instead of `mod.Bar`.

You can put this into a fixture by using the `mocker` fixture from `pytest-mock` or with `unittest.mock.patch`.

```py
@pytest.fixture # With pytest-mock
def mock_bar(mocker):
    return mocker.patch('foomod.Bar')

@pytest.fixture # With stdlib
def mock_bar():
    with patch('foomod.Bar') as mock:
        yield mock

# Usage
def test_foo(mock_bar):
    pass
```

To my knowledge, there is no significant difference between the two approaches. Both are cleaned up when the fixture goes out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following to mock objects with `pytest` without the `fixture` decorator

```py
# path.to.MyClass
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, some_parameter: SomeObject) -> None:
        self.some_value = some_parameter

    def get_something(self) -> str:
        return 'Hello'


# tests.py
from pytest_mock.plugin import MockerFixture
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

def test_with_mock(mocker: MockerFixture) -> None:
    mock_myclass: MagicMock = mocker.patch('path.to.MyClass')

    mock_myclass_get_something: MagicMock = mocker.patch('path.to.MyClass.get_something')
    mock_myclass_get_something.return_value = 'World!'

    assert mock_myclass.get_something() == 'World!'
```

Comment: How to mock the some_value?